# how to search lines have spaces first in text file in python

Tags: python, scripting

I want to search lines contain specific a string in text file.

Example, I search lines contain strings `umask 022`, not lines comment in `/etc/profile` file.

My codes:

```
def check_umask(fname, umask):
   with open(fname) as f:
       return any(umask in line for line in f)
check_umask('/etc/profile','umask 022')
```

With code in above, but it show lines comment:

```
# .....
# By default, we want ... umask 022
       # bla..bla... umask 022
.........
umask 022
```

So, how to show only lines contain `umask 022` script, not lines comment?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the combination of `strip` and `startswith`.

```
def check_umask(fname, umask):
   with open(fname) as f:
       for line in f:
           if not line.strip().startswith('#') and 'umask 022' in line:
               print line
check_umask('/etc/profile','umask 022')
```

**Example:**

```
>>> s = '''# .....
# By default, we want ... umask 022
       # bla..bla... umask 022
.........
umask 022'''.splitlines()
>>> for line in s:
    if not line.strip().startswith('#') and 'umask 022' in line:
        print line


umask 022
>>>
```

or

```
for line in s:
    if re.search(r'^[^#]*umask 022', line):
        print line
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, i suggest you to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
mo = re.search(r'[^#]*umask 022', line)
if mo:
    print(mo.group())
```

Comment: OP showed one line with # not in the begining of the line, so i did not forget

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.find()` to compare indices. If a match isn't found, it returns -1, so we can turn that into a truthy/falsey value by adding 1:

```
for line in content:
    p = line.find('#') + 1
    u = line.find('umask 022') + 1
    if u and (not p or p > u):
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have again the other problems with my case. before "#" is a command valid.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/... # umask 022
```

So, @Raj's script still show this line, althrough it contain "umask 022" in comment.
  So, Have we solution???